# Why does the assoc command in cmd doesn't change the program that opens a file with the specified extension?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command

I have tried a lot, but the assoc command doesn't work for me. 
When I type

```
assoc .html=txtfile
```

the command seems to have been executed as expected. When I check the extension and the associations the .html association has changed to txtfile. But normally it should mean, that the .html files are opened with notepad from now, shouldn't it? Because that is not the case!
I also tried to restart my PC after that.
What have I done wrong?

Comment: There are many ways to do file association. This is the oldest and it overridden by all others. The Docs have been added to over many years. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144104(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: `assoc` only changes the association that's stored in "HKLM\Software\Classes". An association in "HKCU\Software\Classes" overrides the system association, plus Explorer caches associations and protects user selections (i.e. always open with) in "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts".

Comment: Is there another way to do it in cmd?

Comment: If you have (and should have) free reign of the system, then you can use reg.exe to delete Explorer's key for the extension under the "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Fil‌​eExts" key, plus the corresponding "HKCU\Software\Classes" subkey for the extension if that's causing problems. Then run `assoc` to set the system association. This will call `SHChangeNotify`, which should update the shell association the way you want.

Comment: @TheProgrammer perhaps try using the `ftype` command?

Comment: The ftype has a link to Notepad for txtfile. So I don't get why it doesn't work...

Comment: I gave you a link and said this is old and is overridden by many things. So Drag Drop handlers, context menu extensions (they can choose to override simple association). And o0ther things past and present.

Comment: As others have said there are other registry keys that override what `assoc` sets. You can find my solution to validate your `assoc` settings [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1370681/assoc-ftype-does-not-work-properly-on-windows-10/1783975#1783975).

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the Command Prompt as administrator and execute the assoc command again.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please consider adding statements/links in the comments section.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

In the previous response, I mentioned using the command "assoc .html=textfile" in the command line interface (CLI) to associate the ".html" file extension with "textfile" instead of the default association. I clarified that this change will not affect the behavior of opening HTML files in Google Chrome.

I also explained that the "assoc" command is used to associate file extensions with specific file types, but it does not determine the application that opens the files. The default behavior of opening HTML files is typically determined by the operating system or user's preferred settings.

To open HTML files in Google Chrome, you can either set Chrome as the default browser for HTML files through the operating system settings or use the appropriate command or method to open HTML files directly in Chrome.

```
notepad file_name.html
```